# Gracefully exit from a gen_statem while processing a state timeout

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

How do you gracefully exit from a state_timeout in a gen_statem? Generally, for a gen_statem, I can return “stop” or {stop, Reason} from a state function and the statem will terminate. However, if I use a state timeout method, returned from init:

> {ok, StateName, State, {state_timeout, 2000, timeout}}

The handle_event(state_timeout, timeout, StateName, State) method is called after 2000. Returning “stop” from this gives an error…:

the code:

> handle_event(state_timeout, timeout, StateName, State) ->
>   lager:warning("Timeout for device: ~p in State: ~p",
>   [State#state.uuid, StateName]),
>   {stop, timeout};

the error:

> 14:29:56.992 [warning] <0.916.0> handle_event(299):  Timeout for
>   device: undefined in State: init_auth 14:29:56.992 [error] <0.767.0>
>   **Undefined(Undefined):  Lager event handler error_logger_lager_h exited
>   with reason {'EXIT',{{badmatch,[module,{state_timeout,timeout**

What can I return from this function to gracefully exit? Can this be done with state_timeout? If this is an obvious question, please point me in the right direction. The documentation here: http://erlang.org/doc/man/gen_statem.html#type-transition_option doesn’t seem to mention any return from the state_timeout. It seems like I may be able to specify a "next state", but to exit out doesn't seem to be defined

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The system generate an error because the reason associated to the stop message is not `normal`.

in this small example, the state machine exits "gracefully" after 20 timeout conditions reached:

```
-module (statem).

-behaviour(gen_statem).

-export ([start_link/0]).
-export([init/1, callback_mode/0, terminate/3, code_change/4,handle_event/4]).

start_link() ->
    gen_statem:start_link({local,?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).

init([]) ->
    {ok, state1, #{info => 0, call => 0 , cast => 0, timeout => 0},[{timeout, 2000, timeout_event}]}.


callback_mode() ->
    handle_event_function.

handle_event(timeout,_EventContent,_State,#{timeout := 20}) ->
    io:format("max timeout count reached~n"),
    {stop, normal};
handle_event(EventType,EventContent,State,Data) ->
    io:format("EtventType : ~p~nEventContent : ~p~nState : ~p~nData : ~p~n", [EventType,EventContent,State,Data]),
    NewData = process_event(EventType,EventContent,State,Data),
    {next_state, State, NewData,[{timeout, 2000, timeout_event}]}.

terminate(_Reason, _State, _Data) ->
    ok.

code_change(_Vsn, State, Data, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State, Data}.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

process_event(info,_EventContent,_State,Data) ->
    maps:update(info, maps:get(info, Data)+1, Data);
process_event(cast,_EventContent,_State,Data) ->
    maps:update(cast, maps:get(cast, Data)+1, Data);
process_event(timeout,_EventContent,_State,Data) ->
    maps:update(timeout, maps:get(timeout, Data)+1, Data);
process_event({call,From},EventContent,_State,Data) ->
    gen_statem:reply(From, {got,EventContent}),
    maps:update(call, maps:get(call, Data)+1, Data).
```

in works:

```
74> c(statem).                     
{ok,statem}
75> {ok,Pid} = statem:start_link().
{ok,<0.197.0>}
EtventType : timeout               
EventContent : timeout_event
State : state1
Data : #{call => 0,cast => 0,info => 0,timeout => 0}
EtventType : timeout              
EventContent : timeout_event
State : state1
Data : #{call => 0,cast => 0,info => 0,timeout => 1}
76> Pid ! hello.                  
EtventType : info
EventContent : hello
State : state1
Data : #{call => 0,cast => 0,info => 0,timeout => 2}
hello
EtventType : timeout               
EventContent : timeout_event
State : state1
Data : #{call => 0,cast => 0,info => 1,timeout => 2}
EtventType : timeout              
EventContent : timeout_event
State : state1
Data : #{call => 0,cast => 0,info => 1,timeout => 3}
77> gen_statem:cast(Pid,cast_msg).
EtventType : cast
EventContent : cast_msg
State : state1
Data : #{call => 0,cast => 0,info => 1,timeout => 4}
ok
...
80> gen_statem:call(Pid,call_msg).
EtventType : {call,{<0.190.0>,#Ref<0.571135265.1570766849.45359>}}
EventContent : call_msg
State : state1
Data : #{call => 0,cast => 3,info => 1,timeout => 17}
{got,call_msg}
EtventType : timeout
EventContent : timeout_event
State : state1
Data : #{call => 1,cast => 3,info => 1,timeout => 17}
...
EtventType : timeout              
EventContent : timeout_event
State : state1
Data : #{call => 2,cast => 4,info => 1,timeout => 19}
max timeout count reached
84>
```

**{EDIT]**

It works the same with the syntax state_timeout (I didn't dig too much to understand the difference)

There is a syntax error in your snippet, the actions must be enclosed in a list (even with one single action). I tried this modified code and it works:

```
-module (statem).

-behaviour(gen_statem).

-export ([start_link/0]).
-export([init/1, callback_mode/0, terminate/3, code_change/4,handle_event/4]).

start_link() ->
    gen_statem:start_link({local,?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).

init([]) ->
    {ok, state1, #{info => 0, call => 0 , cast => 0, timeout => 0},[{state_timeout, 2000, timeout}]}.


callback_mode() ->
    handle_event_function.

handle_event(state_timeout,_EventContent,_State,#{timeout := 20}) ->
    io:format("max timeout count reached~n"),
    {stop, normal};
handle_event(EventType,EventContent,State,Data) ->
    io:format("EtventType : ~p~nEventContent : ~p~nState : ~p~nData : ~p~n", [EventType,EventContent,State,Data]),
    NewData = process_event(EventType,EventContent,State,Data),
    {next_state, State, NewData,[{state_timeout, 2000, timeout}]}.

terminate(_Reason, _State, _Data) ->
    ok.

code_change(_Vsn, State, Data, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State, Data}.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

process_event(info,_EventContent,_State,Data) ->
    maps:update(info, maps:get(info, Data)+1, Data);
process_event(cast,_EventContent,_State,Data) ->
    maps:update(cast, maps:get(cast, Data)+1, Data);
process_event(state_timeout,_EventContent,_State,Data) ->
    maps:update(timeout, maps:get(timeout, Data)+1, Data);
process_event({call,From},EventContent,_State,Data) ->
    gen_statem:reply(From, {got,EventContent}),
    maps:update(call, maps:get(call, Data)+1, Data).
```

Comment: This is using the timeout method, not the state_timeout. Do you happen to know why the state_timeout method doesn't work?